# How SQL query result insert in temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query (SQL Server) and it generate reports, I want to store that exact report in temp table so I can play with it later. Now question is do I need to create temp table first and then store SQL query result into it, or is there any way to dynamically create table and store query result?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Look at [SELECT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx).  This will create a new table for you, which can be temporary if you want by prefixing the table name with a pound sign (#).

For example, you can do:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #YourTempTable
FROM YourReportQuery
```

Comment: Borrowed from another thread, `#yourtemptable` does not need to be created first.

Comment: This won't work and will throw error as Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT' if YourReportQuery is query and not database table.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `select ... into ...` to create and populate a temp table and then query the temp table to return the result.

```
select *
into #TempTable
from YourTable

select *
from #TempTable
```

Comment: Do i need to create #TempTable first before running that query/

Comment: No you don't. If you want to fill a table that already exist with rows you need to use a different syntax.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL:

```
create table temp as select * from original_table
```

Comment: Modifying temp to #temp does not work. Error message:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: This is a structure that works in MySQL and possibly others. Op didn't specify which server type is being used, but since he called it SQL Server, I would guess it is Microsoft SQL Server. 

By the way, for others that need to use this for MySQL, @Hunter's answer would create a new table. To create a new temporary table, you need to add the TEMPORARY keyword like this:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptbl AS SELECT ... FROM originaltbl

Comment: The tag "SQL Server" is only for Microsoft SQL, not other like Mysql or ORACLE:

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
exec('drop table #tab') -- you can add condition 'if table exists'
exec('select * into #tab from tab')
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your existing reporting query  is

```
Select EmployeeId,EmployeeName 
from Employee 
Where EmployeeId>101 order by EmployeeName
```

and you have to save this data into temparory table then you query goes to

```
Select EmployeeId,EmployeeName 
into #MyTempTable 
from Employee 
Where EmployeeId>101 order by EmployeeName
```