# SQL: Using CONCAT to merge 2 columns, then putting the result into a temp table & column

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, temp-tables

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Name) 
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) As Name from tbl_name
```

I've tried to do this in a number of different variations and can't get it to work. Please can somebody assist?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? `CONCAT` is a MySQL function, but `#TempTable` isn't a way to name temporary tables in MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar Could be [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx), but you're right, it needs to be clear.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I'm using mysql on wampserver

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of: [How SQL query result insert in temp table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323757/how-sql-query-result-insert-in-temp-table)

Correct way in mssql:

```
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;

    SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) As Name
    INTO #TempTable
      FROM tbl_name;

    SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

[mssql]

Same in mysql:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable AS (
    SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) As Name
    FROM tbl_name);
    SELECT * FROM TempTable;
```

[mysql] - the "AS" seems to be optional in mysql becase the selection goes automatically to temptable

Comment: Thanks but I need mysql. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you don't create temporary tables by using `#TempTable` as the table name, you use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable
SELECT CONCAT(FIrstName, ' ', LastName) AS Name
FROM tbl_name
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the list of names into the TempTable?

Comment: The `SELECT` does that.